# Google Earth with WPF without using HwndHost

Tags: google-earth, google-earth-plugin

In my project, I want to embed Google Earth inside one of the User controls. I have seen many example in web where people say how to do it using winforms. I have seen few more sample who actually integrate it in **WPF** but using **WindowsFormsHost/HwndHost** *I am eliminating this to avoid the airspace problem*.

*What exactly in my mind is something like to have a rendering Engine class and have an image in the control and use back buffering to draw data from rendering Engine class on the Image.*

Has any one integrated Google Earth without using WindowsFormsHost/HwndHost?  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using D3DImage. WPF gives a callback to fill in the back buffer. Have a look at great sample by Dr WPF on Code Project. You can find the sample here.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28526/Introduction-to-D3DImage

~Yogesh